# Grants Calendars Privacy access Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ekevent, ekeventstore

In my code I am handling all cases for ios 6 calendar privacy, if the user allows access to calendars, i called some method like following:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

The problem is that method specified in the selector never being called, But if i changed the calling mechanism to:

```
[self reloadData];
```

the method called successfully.

What do you think about this case? is there any reason for this issue?

Why preform selector does not working if it is used after grants the access to calendars in iOS 6?

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing afterDelay? See: [stackoverflow.com/questions/7219131/performselector-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219131/performselector-not-working).

Also, does it work if you use `performSelectorInBackground` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your response i will check your suggestion and get back

Comment: Thank you, now it works fine, I removed afterDelay:  [self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil];