# performSelector not working after checking that object responds to it

Tags: objective-c, selector

In my unit tests I have a test failing because a method is not called. The code fragment of the class under test is:

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(updateFromDict:)]){
    [object performSelector:@selector(updateFromDict:) withObject:objectsDict];
}
```

However when in the debugger I try to step into the method nothing happens and the breakpoint on object updateFromDict: does not fire. It does not crash. The if clause is true, verified by putting a breakpoint on the perform selector line.

I don't see how it can be related to [PerformSelector not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219131/performselector-not-working) as this should equivalent to directly calling [object updateFromDict:objectsDict] on the same thread ([Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:))

**update:**
Based on the comments I inserted the NSLog statements which revealed the problem in my method implementation which caused it to not do what it was supposed to do. 
For some reason the debugger did not work.

Comment: You will likely get much better information by just adding NSLog statements at appropriate places to check the values of `object` and `[object respondsToSelector:@selector(updateFromDict:)]` (and perhaps even `objectsDict`), and an NSLog statement inside of `updateFromDict:`. The debugger is useful, but can often cause as much confusion as it solves.

Comment: include the `updateFromDict` method in question

Comment: Perhaps you should also check if `object` is not released after current method scope ends.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should debug this issue by placing nslog statements inside if condition and inside method definition of updateFromDict: method.

Also it might happen that while the if condition results in true the instance which responds to selector 'object' exists and till the time perform selector statement is called the 'object' is released.

Comment: Aslo it would be more informative, if you could provide with the method definition of updateFromDict:

Answer (score 0):

Please read this link from Apple developer sight
[How to use respondsToSelector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:)

So your object may not inherit that method you are trying to call it may not be going the condition.